# Which is better using method or direct call of resource?

Tags: java, android

i have a class that have lot of string resource from value-string.

my question is which is better using method like this:

```
private static String getString(int id){
    return Resources.getSystem().getString(id);
}
```

or direct call like this:

```
Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.text_id);
```

I want to know what is the right way to such situations

Thanks

Comment: I would say use a method if its used in a lot of places. the objective should be to keep the code clean and readable.

Comment: Just for the record: method names go camelCase in Java. Always. Only class names start with an UpperCase!

Answer (score 2):

follow First approach but make little bit change show in below code.

make method and pass into parameter in this..

```
void methodName(@StringRes final int title)
```

when you call method then pass only

```
R.string.keyname //
```

Answer (score 1):

The second one is better because you don't have to declare a new variable. 
You can create this first kind of method when you want to aim on a specific instance. There, you just call the same method. So, take the easiest one.